# select multiple columns with max from one column and distinct on another

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

So I want to select all the records with distinct contractNo and the max versionNo.

So I have a table like this:

```
| username | contractNo | versionNo |
|===================================|
| lucian   |     1      |     1     |
| john     |     2      |     1     |
| lucian   |     2      |     1     |
| kris     |     3      |     1     |
| lucian   |     1      |     2     |
| david    |     4      |     1     |
| lucian   |     1      |     4     |
| adam     |     5      |     1     |
| lucian   |     2      |     2     |
| kris     |     3      |     2     |
| lucian   |     3      |     1     |
| lucian   |     1      |     3     |
| lucian   |     1      |     5     |
| lucian   |     4      |     1     |
```

and I want to select the following records:

```
| username | contractNo | versionNo |
|===================================|
| lucian   |     1      |     5     |
| lucian   |     2      |     2     |
| lucian   |     3      |     1     |
| lucian   |     4      |     1     |
```

I have this query, however this only returns them in descending order ordered by contractNo and versionNo.

```
SELECT username, contractNo, versionNo 

FROM contracts 

WHERE useremail = 'lucian'

order by contractNo, versionNo desc;
```

I believe that I need to do some kind of join, but I am not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what that is. I am running my queries through SQL Developer it that's what you were asking.. ?

Comment: Joins are for 2 or more tables, but you only indicate one above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    username
    ,contractNo
    ,MAX(versionNo) AS versionNo
FROM contracts
WHERE username = 'lucian'
GROUP BY
    username
    ,contractNo
ORDER BY contractNo ASC
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Use in clause  subselect and group by

```
SELECT username, contractNo, versionNo 
FROM contracts 
where  (username, contractNo, versionNo) in 
        (select username, contractNo, max(versionNo) 
            from contracts group by username, contractNo )
and username = 'lucian';
```